# How do I determine what Action triggered a trigger that handles multiple events

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ddl-trigger

I have a database trigger that logs DDL changes. It has the folowing format

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Log_DDL_Changes]

ON DATABASE
FOR 
CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, 
CREATE_INDEX, ALTER_INDEX, DROP_INDEX, 
CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE,
CREATE_VIEW, ALTER_VIEW, DROP_VIEW,
CREATE_FUNCTION, ALTER_FUNCTION, DROP_FUNCTION, RENAME

--Fires only for CREATE / ALTER / DROP Table and PROCs
AS 

BEGIN
.
.
.
END
```

I'd like to add special handling whenever a table, view or index is created or changed.

How can I determine which event triggered the trigger for a TRIGGER that handles multiple events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use something like this in your trigger:

```
SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. While this may work, I'm thinking that there ias a better way than to parse the SQL command. I feel like I should be able to key off of teh EVENT names that appear in the FOR CLAUSE. If I have to, I'll sooner break up my trigger into separate triggers so I can tell what event got me to execute

Comment: @ChadD That's why I said "*something like this*".  There's a lot of options, but I have changed it to to more closely reflect your comment's preferences.

Comment: Ah, I now see your edit. That is exactly what i was looking for. TY!